# Debugging DataBinding errors when using Dagger, Room and LiveData

Tags: android, android-room, dagger, android-livedata

In my Android project I am using Android Studio 3.0-beta6, retrofit2 for rest calls, Room for persistence, LiveData for reactive programming using RxJava / RxAndroid. There are at severals annotationProcessors in use:

1. android.arch.lifecycle:compiler
2. android.arch.persistence.room:compiler
3. com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler
4. com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor
5. org.projectlombok:lombok

Every time I add a new Retrofit2 service, model classes with Room annotations, Room Dao classes I find that I run into a databinding generation error:

`Error:(3, 27) error: cannot find symbol class DataBindingComponent`

A huge list of "cannot find symbol" errors are emmitted but the root cause of my problem is often not emitted. Debugging the root cause takes a huge amount of time since the error reporting seems very weak.

After being burned a few times here are some tactics I use to isolate the problem in such cases:

1. Shelve my changes and introduce the changes in small increments and do a clean Rebuild after blowing away build and schema output folders of my app. Typically this means first introducing model class changes. Next introducing Jackson converters that are needed for Room to persist non-primitive types in my Room Entity model classes. Finally introducing the Dao classes and the Room Database subclass.
2. Check Entity classes to make sure they have @PrimaryKey, @Entity, @TypeConverters Room annotations. Make sure that TypeConverter classes are specifying the converter class FooConverter and not the class Foo being converted
3. Check Dao classes to make sure that there are no copy paste errors in tablename within @Query annotation

Yet there are times when I am still getting a databining generation error and the root cause is unknown.

I am wondering if there are any good techniques to isolate the root cause in such a acsenario. Are there ways to turn on debug logging in the annotation processors (specially Room).

TIA for any guidance on this. I suspect many people are facing this situation.

Answer (score 4):

The following technique gave me meaningful errors in the Messages pane of Android Studio about my problem in my Dao class. It told me that I had a typo in my tablename in Room's `@Query` annotation. What gave the clearer message was that I changed by build.gradle to increase the max number of errors emitted by the java compiler.

I added the following code at the end of my build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "5000"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Thanks for the idea!
For kotlin kapt you should use following: 

subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("kotlin-kapt")) {
            kapt {
                javacOptions {
                    option("-Xmaxerrs", 500)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the problem is that Dagger, Databinding and Room uses an Annotation Processor.  That means that one code generator get issues while processing corrupt code by another.

Ive [added an issue long time ago](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/43). Google-Team want to improve that, but usually you can see the errors in your gradle log straight at the top.

After developing a little bit with those libraries you'll find the issues easy.

Comment: My problem was that with a largish project I was not seeing the actual error as error reporting stops after 200 erros. See my answer below that made the actual error show.

Answer (score -1):

In your build.gradle module level use...

```
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
...
sourceSets {
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
        main.java.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main")]
    }
...
}
    ...

        compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12" 
    ...
        kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-beta1"
        kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12"
        kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.3"
```

In your project build.gradle

```
apply from: 'buildsystem/dependencies.gradle'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        //classpath "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```